# Working with EnumSet

Tags: java

This code works, but with a `try/catch box` .

```
public enum AccentuationUTF8 {/** */
        é, /** */è, /** */ç, /** */à, /** */ù, /** */
        ä, /** */ë, /** */ö, /** */ï, /** */ü, /** */
        â, /** */ê, /** */î, /** */ô, /** */û, /** */
}
......

    final EnumSet<AccentuationUTF8> esUtf8 = EnumSet.noneOf(AccentuationUTF8.class);
    final String[] acc1 = {"é", "à", "u"};
    for (final String string : acc1) {
        try { // The ontologic problem
            esUtf8.add(AccentuationUTF8.valueOf(string));
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            System.out.println(string + " not an accent.");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(esUtf8.size() + "\t" + esUtf8.toString()
```

output :

```
u   not an accent.
2   [é, à]
```

I want to generate an EnumSet with all accents of a word or of sentence.

*Edit after comments*

- Is it possible to manage such an `EnumSet` without using `try` (needed by `AccentuationUTF8.valueOf(string)`?
- Is better way to code ?

**FINAL EDIT**
Your responses suggest me a good solution : because `EnumSet.contains(Object)`, `throw an Exception`, change it : create a temporary `HashSet` able to return a `null` without Exception.
 
So the *ugly* `try/catch` is now removed, code is now :

```
final Set<String> setTmp = new HashSet<>(AccentsUTF8.values().length);
for (final AccentsUTF8 object : AccentsUTF8.values()) {
    setTmp.add(object.toString());
}
final EnumSet<AccentsUTF8> esUtf8 = EnumSet.noneOf(AccentsUTF8.class);
final String[] acc1 = {"é", "à", "u"};
for (final String string : acc1) {
    if (setTmp.contains(string)) {
        esUtf8.add(AccentsUTF8.valueOf(string));
    } else {
        System.out.println(string + " not an accent.");
    }
}
System.out.println(esUtf8.size() + "\t" + esUtf8.toString()
```

Thanks for attention you paid for.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think an enum is the best approach here - partly because it's only going to work for valid Java identifiers.

It looks like what you really want is just a `Set<Character>`, with something like:

```
Set<Character> accentsInText = new HashSet<Character>();
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    Character c = text.charAt(i);
    if (ALL_ACCENTS.contains(c)) {
        accentsInText.add(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 For simplicity, `accents` could even be a `String` which might not be much slower.

Comment: I've thought  at your answer, but I want to use EnumSet easy to manage (and said speed by Sun/Oracle) for stressed queries on words letters

Comment: @cl-r: Do you really think that catching an exception on every non-accent character is going to give you speed? In what way is your code really "easier to manage" than mine?

Comment: It just my problem : `ALL_ACCENTS.contains(c)` throw an exception if it an Enum for verify, a Set can be modified, and I would avoid this possibility.

Comment: The easy to manage is for output querying in safe (and I hope speed) way from an OODB, not necessary for formating input data